# Why is my three-js z-index not creating a smooth curve

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, glsl

I am trying to wrap a plane around a cone in three.js using a depth-map for learning purpose. I import the depth-map into my vertex-shader with a uniform, then get the color-value from it at the given uv-coordinate and then move the z-value of the vertex by the given color-value:

```java
// Import depthmap
uniform sampler2D uDepthMap;

varying vec2 vUv;
 
void main() {   
    vUv = uv; 
    vec3 pos = position;

    // Get depthmap green value
    float bumpValue = texture2D(uDepthMap, vUv).g;

    // Move Z by greenvalue of depthmap
    pos.z = pos.z + bumpValue * 7.0;
    
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( pos, 1.0 );
}
```

Given the depth-map below (a smooth gradient) I am expecting my plane to make a smooth curve, but at the far x vertices the plane looks like shown in the image.

[image: Depth map and resulting z-index]

So I am wondering how to use the depth-map to correctly bend the plane in a continuous curve?

### Edit:

Here's my plane and my camera-settings;

```js
   const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 1, 60);

   const planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(10,5,128,64);
   const planeMat = new THREE.ShaderMaterial(
            {
                wireframe: true,
                vertexShader: vshader,
                uniforms: this.uniforms,
                fragmentShader: fshader
            }
        );
```

Apart from that everything is at default settings.

Comment: The displacement is computed per vertex. The clip space coordinates between the vertices are interpolated during [Rasterization](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Rendering_Pipeline_Overview#Rasterization). How many vertices do you have what is the `minFilter` of `uDepthMap` [Texture](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/textures/Texture)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So the sides just appear to be wrong because they're further in the distance and therefore the interpolated angle is less than it should be? I am trying to understand what you're saying there. The plane is 10 by 5 and it has 128 segments. I am not aware of the minFilter, but according to THREE Js docs it should therefore default to `THREE.LinearMipmapLinearFilter`.